# Can I create dropdown rows dynamically for a table using html and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic

I've created a table dynamically, but now I want to create a dropdown row on demand.  I have an onclick handler for each row.  Upon clicking, this row should drop something downward (like a hidden div but unfortunately these cannot be easily created in a dynamic setting, as there's not a way to assign a unique id at row creation.  Is this even possible in Javascript/jQuery?  or, preferably, twitter bootstrap?

```
function buildHtmlTable(portalData, tablename) {
    var columns = [];
    var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');
    var n = 0;
    if (tablename == "order-table") {
        document.getElementById("dist-name").innerText = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(portalData[0], null, 2))["Company Name"];
        n = 1;
    }
    for (var i = 0 ; i < portalData.length ; i++) {
        var rowHash = portalData[i];
        for (var key in rowHash) {
            if ($.inArray(key, columns) == -1) {
                columns.push(key);
                headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
            }
        }
    }
    $('#' + tablename).append(headerTr$);
    for (i = 0 ; i < portalData.length ; i++) {
        var row$ = $('<tr/>');
        for (var colIndex = n ; colIndex < columns.length ; colIndex++) {  // n is how many columns to drop, based on table name
            var cellValue = portalData[i][columns[colIndex]];
            if (cellValue == null) {
                cellValue = "";
            }
            row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
        }
        $('#' + tablename).append(row$);
    }

    // Drop unnecessary columns
    for(i = 0 ; i<n; i++) {
        $("#order-table").find('td,th').first().remove();
    }
    if (tablename == "order-table") {
        var tablerows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        for (var x in tablerows) {      
            tablerows[x].classList.add("clickable");
            tablerows[x].setAttribute(data-toggle,"collapse");
            tablerows[x].setAttribute(data-target,"");
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: why can't you create a unique id at row creation? It would help a lot to see your code

Comment: Because said rows don't exist.  The idea is to create invisible divs with details panes and then, using an ajax call, when i click the row, said div appears below it like an accordion table and makes a backend query.

Comment: so in your `portalData` for loop you can't add any kind of identifier about the data it holds? like adding `row$.attr("id", "myID")` right before `row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));`

Comment: how would i dynamically generate unique ids though if i have no clue what the number of incoming rows is?  btw if you can give me a solid answer here, post it as an answer so i can accept it :)

Comment: You're looping to create rows.  Each iteration has a counter, which is unique in the context/duration of that `for` loop, right?  Prepend a string and an underscore in front of the iteration number (e.g. "mytablerow_2" for the 2nd pass through the loop), and you have a unique identifier.

Comment: but i want to create this hidden row as soon as the click happens. I don't need to be loading possibly 100 empty divs that are going to screw up what i'm doing.  What would be NICE is if i could zebra stripe the table (i know how to do that) and then make the new div take on the color of whatever it dropped from